# How can I threshold an image?

Tags: matlab, image-processing, homomorphic-filter, image-thresholding

I need to apply thresholding to an image which has already gone through a homomorphic filter.

My threshold value must be the **mean** + **standard-deviation** of image intensity.

I used the thresholding [code by Jan Motl](https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/40856-bernsen-local-image-thresholding?focused=3844321&tab=function) as follows:

```
function J = bernsen_thres(I)
    T = thres_val(I);

    J = bernsen(I, [T T],20,'replicate');
end

function T = thres_val(I)
    mn = mean(I(:));
    sd = std(double(I(:)));
    thres = round((mn+sd));

    if(is_odd(thres))
        T = thres;
    else
        T = thres+1;
    end

 function ret = is_odd(val)
    if(mod(val,2) == 0);
        ret = 0;
    else
        ret = 1;
    end
```

I used the homomorphic filter [code from Steve Eddins](http://blogs.mathworks.com/steve/2013/06/25/homomorphic-filtering-part-1/) as follows,

```
clear_all();

I = gray_imread('cameraman.png');
I = steve_homo_filter(I);

Ithres = bernsen_thres(I);

imshowpair(I, Ithres, 'montage')
```

But the output is totally black,

[image]

**What should I do to fix this?**

Comment: Put a breakpoint and check what `thres` is. (Tell us after you check).

Comment: @TonyTannous, thres = 181;

Comment: Can you add the code for `steve_homo_filter` & `brensen` in case the later one is not a built in function ?

Comment: @TonyTannous, already linked the URLs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay. I solved the problem.

```
clear_all();

I = gray_imread('cameraman.png');    

Ihmf = mat2gray(steve_homo_filter(I));

T = thres_val(I)/255

Ithres = Ihmf > T;

imshowpair(Ihmf, Ithres, 'montage');
```

There were two issues,

1. Intensities of the output of the homomorphic filter were not between 0 and 1. I fixed that by applying `mat2gray()`.
2. Output of `thres_val()` was 181 in this case. That value was divided by 255 in order to bring it between 0 and 1.